# Is there a way to upload an external folder in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins

I have a set of custom html pages that are not made with Wordpress in folder DIR

In the wordpress blog I have a web page called SPECIAL that only some users can access (after being authenticated). I would like to know if there is a way to allow those users to open the web pages in DIR (in a comfortable way)

For now i am using a very non-pratical solution: I make a zip archive of that folder, upload it from the Admin interface of Wordpress, using WP-Filebase, and put a link to the DIR.zip in the web page SPECIAL.

Yes I agree that my solution is ridiculous. Please help me find a better one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the folder containing html pages protected from being access directly? I.E. if someone knows the full addresses of those html files, can view them or is there any protection?

Comment: There are several "Related" questions to the right. Do none of those help?

Comment: @G.M. Yes they are protected. Now as i use the plugin WP-Filebase to upload the media the link to my DIR.zip won't work if the user is not authenticated. But as you can see my solution is very unpratical.

Comment: @s_ha_dum yes i really tried but none of them talk about how to deal with folders. When i upload only the DIR.zip i have no problems with rights. It s just that i would like to upload the unzipped folder.

Comment: Just uploading to a particular location is the first part of the problem, and you've skipped over that.

Comment: It seems I explained badly, but yes It is part of the problem.